# Multiple insertion of one value in sqlalchemy statement to pandas

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have constructed a sql clause where I reference the same table as `a` and `b` to compare the two geometries as a postgis command.

I would like to pass a value into the sql statement using the `%s` operator and read the result into a pandas dataframe using `to_sql, params kwargs`. Currently my code will allow for one value to be passed to one `%s` but i'm looking for multiple insertions of the same list of values.

I'm connecting to a postgresql database using psycopg2.

Simplified code is below

```
sql = """
SELECT
    st_distance(a.the_geom, b.the_geom, true) AS dist
    FROM
        (SELECT
           table.*
           FROM table
           WHERE id in %s) AS a,

        (SELECT
           table.*
           FROM table
           WHERE id in %s) AS b
WHERE a.nid <> b.nid """

sampList = (14070,11184)
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con=conn, params = [sampList])
```

Basically i'm looking to replace both `%s` with the sampList value in both places. The code as written will only replace the first value indicating `': list index out of range`. If I adjust to having one `%s` and replacing the second in statement with numbers the code runs, but ultimately I would like away to repeat those values.

Comment: You have to pass in lists of parameter placeholders.

Comment: You want the two `%s` parameters to refer to *the same* list of values?

Comment: @wildplasser, yes the two `%s` parameters referring to the same list

Comment: You don't need the subqueries, Just a plain (anti-) join will do. BTW: your question is about passing a list to a prepared statement. Using it twice is only a detail.

Answer (score 1):

- You dont need the subqueries, just join the table with itself:

  `SELECT a.*, b.* -- or whatwever
          , st_distance(a.the_geom, b.the_geom, true) AS dist
          FROM ztable a
          JOIN ztable b ON a.nid < b.nid 
          WHERE a.id IN (%s)
            AND b.id IN (%s)
          ;`
- avoid repetition by using a CTE (this may be non-optimal, performance-wise)

  `WITH zt AS (
          SELECT * FROM ztable
          WHERE id IN (%s)
          )
  SELECT a.*, b.* -- or whatever
          , st_distance(a.the_geom, b.the_geom, true) AS dist
          FROM zt a
          JOIN zt b ON a.nid < b.nid 
          ;`
- Performance-wise, I would just stick to the first version, and supply the list-argument twice. (or refer to it twice, using a FORMAT() construct)

Answer (score 0):

first of all i would recommend you to use [updated SQL from @wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38882015/5741205) - it's much better and more efficient way to do that.

now you can do the following:

```
sql_ = """\
WITH zt AS (
        SELECT * FROM ztable
        WHERE id IN ({})
        )
SELECT a.*, b.* -- or whatever
        , st_distance(a.the_geom, b.the_geom, true) AS dist
        FROM zt a
        JOIN zt b ON a.nid < b.nid 
"""
sampList = (14070,11184)

sql = sql_.format(','.join(['?' for x in sampList]))

df = pd.read_sql(sql, con=conn, params=sampList)
```

dynamically generated SQL with parameters (AKA: prepared statements, bind variables, etc.):

```
In [27]: print(sql)
WITH zt AS (
        SELECT * FROM ztable
        WHERE id IN (?,?)
        )
SELECT a.*, b.* -- or whatever
        , st_distance(a.the_geom, b.the_geom, true) AS dist
        FROM zt a
        JOIN zt b ON a.nid < b.nid
```

Comment: Could be a nice addition. (sorry, I dont know anything about ORMs, since they confuse me. and others ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser, i hope you don't mind that i've borrowed your SQL (i have already said "thank you" for that) ;)

Comment: No, not at all. I like collaborative effort!